# vbc.exe takes up all free memory when debugging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, out-of-memory

I recently encountered a problem debugging my asp.net webforms application programmed in vb.net

When a particular form is opened during debugging, the vbc.exe process takes all available memory and locks the entire system until msvmon hangs.

This process is repeated again and again until vbc.exe and w3wp.exe are killed manually

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional, debugging on local machine with IIS

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was because of an orfan div close tag between ContentTemplate and UpdatePanel closing tags.